# Live data for: Bond Yield and Dollar Index

Tags: market-data

Im looking for live data feed of Bond Yield and DXY.
I like to use it in R.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you specify which bonds and how much you're willing to pay?

Comment: Looking at 10Y, 30Y and some European as well, now I follow Investing.com but like to build my own kind of setup, investing.com offer free data so If I can't find free source I will stick to this

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can check on Quandl.. One of the best free financial data source

Comment: [Quand doesn't have live data.](http://help.quandl.com/article/81-does-quandl-have-real-time-intraday-or-tick-data)

Comment: @BobJansen - Do you think anybody would provide live data for free.. :)